# Setting background image randomly from many subfolders

Tags: php, css, background-image

I am trying to randomly set the background image of a webpage from several subfolders, but the image as the same name.
For example:
The mail forlder could be profiles then mlhrs then RVS

and inside the (RVS) folder you will have an x number or subfolders, and in every each of them you will have the profile.jpg image

my goal is that every time the page is reloaded, the image changes randomly from all the (RVS) subfoders

how can i do it?

i found this code, its almost what i need, but i dont know how to change to the best way:

can you help me?
many thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>404</title>
    </head>

    <body id="Background404">
        <p>404-Page not found. <a href="http://url.com">Home.</a></p>
    <?php
        $dir = './images';
        $fileNames = array();
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            $handle = opendir($dir);
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file) && is_readable($dir.'/'.$file)){
                    $fileNames[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
            $fileNames = array_reverse($fileNames);
            print_r($fileNames);
        }
        $totalLength = count($fileNames);
        $randInt = rand(0, $totalLength -1);
        $randFile = $fileNames[$randInt];
        echo $randFile;
        echo "<style> #Background404{background: url('./images/$randFile');}</style>";
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to randomly use shuffle

Here the solution code

`````
        $fileNames = shuffle($fileNames); // Shuffle All Array Files
        $randFile = end($fileNames); /*Get Last File Name Array (Last File Is Always Randomly, Becase We Did shuffle before get last element*/
        echo $randFile;
        echo "<style> #Background404{background: url('./images/$randFile');}</style>";````
`````

Comment: Thanks sasindu, but it Didnt works. It Didnt choose ONLY the profille.jpg files from all the subforders that exist on profiles/mlhrs/rvs